# Bootstrap 3 "navbar-fixed-top" overlaps content on resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I'm converting over to bootstrap 3, and am loving the "fixed-top" feature.

It was noticed though that when you resize the window the navbar overlaps the content. Example:

**http://www.clipartillustration.com/**

Whats the "trick" to get it to behave properly? I tried moving the navbar above the actual header, assuming it would "push down" in the typical way, but it appears that does not happen and something is over-riding the rules.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using jQuery to check and reset things on device or browser based changes:

```
//window sizing and responsive adjustments for devices

    function ss_adjust_body_padding(){

        var nav_height = $('#ss_fixed_nav').height();

        $("body").css({ paddingTop: nav_height });


    }

    symbiostock_adjust_body_padding();

    $(window).on('resize', function () {

        ss_adjust_body_padding();

    });
```